# How to loop a javascript page that handles requests?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to loop this page for my chrome extension using javascript. What it does is it should keep running until it gets a response from "chrome.tabs.sendMessage" to stop running. The response function from "chrome.tabs.sendMessage" sends the correct boolean, but the rest of the code below does not work. When I run this code, console.log(cont) prints first, but console.log(response[0]) should be running first. I think it's an issue with async programming, but I am new to javascript and this kind of programming so I'm not sure how to fix it. Any advice or help is appreciated, thanks!

```
var temp = false;

function injectTheScript() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

     chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
         chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "utilities.js"}, function(){
             chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, name, function(response){
                temp = response[0];
                console.log(response[0]);
            });
        });
    });
    return temp;
}

function nextName() {
    var cont = true;
    while(cont){
        cont = injectTheScript();
        console.log(cont); //this gets printed first but should be printed second
    }
}

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', nextName);
```

This page is popup.js btw, it is the script behind popup.html, what the chrome extension shows when you click the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each JavaScript script's context is single-threaded so your synchronous `while` loop will keep running forever in one event loop task, meaning none of the asynchronous callbacks of query(), executeScript(), and sendMessage() will ever run, and your extension will consume 100% CPU endlessly.

The solution is to make the loop asynchronous and let injectTheScript return the content script's response value via `Promise`:

```
function injectTheScript() {
  return new Promise(resolve => { 
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'utilities.js'}, () => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, name, resolve);
      });
    });
  });
}

async function nextName() {
  while (await injectTheScript()) {
    console.log('yay');
  }
}
```

The above code expects your onMessage listener in content script to return a boolean value via sendResponse:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // do something
  // ..............
  sendResponse(true); // or false
});
```

See tutorials on `Promise` and asynchronous JavaScript for more info if needed.